# After using git clean, I have deleted files being detected as changes?

Tags: git, version-control, git-tfs

So I have a git repository. I'm using git 1.7.9 running under Cygwin/Windows 8.

This git repository has this weird behavior so that it thinks that some subdirectories of a certain directory is tracked, but the actual directory containing them is not.

So, I get weirdness like this:

```
$ git reset --hard
$ git status
#untracked files
foo
$ git clean -fd
removing foo
$ git status
#changes not staged
D foo/bar/whatever.txt
```

But then, going the other way and adding the files:

```
$ git add foo
$ git status
# changes not staged
A foo/bar/whatever.txt
```

And if I commit from there, then it will of course put out crazy conflicts when trying to push.

Occasionally a `git reset --hard` fixes it, but sometimes not. I've found the best way to get rid of it is to check out a new branch, delete everything in my working copy and run `git reset --hard`.

Has anyone else ever experienced this weird behavior? I'm using git-tfs, which may mean this  is a bug in that, but it is, for the most part, a regular git repository, so I don't think that matters.

Comment: What is in your `.gitignore` (and `foo/.gitignore` and `foo/bar/.gitignore` if they exist)? Also, what does `git ls-tree -r HEAD -- foo` tell you about files in `foo` that are being tracked? Are either `foo` or `bar` symbolic links instead of directories?

Comment: perhaps (but not likely) a .gitattributes problem with end lines?
That's not a git-tfs problem because git-tfs don't touch your workspace folder (especially when you don't call it ;) )

Comment: btw have you tried upgrading to git 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

`git clean -fd` skips over files that match any of the entries in your `.gitignore`, which I am assuming is the case. So make sure there is no regex matching `foo/bar/whatever.txt` in any of your `.gitignore`s.

On more thing make sure that the `foo/bar/whatever.txt` is not locked, which could be preventing the cleaning.